# How to deal with this situation concerning an interface implementation using generics?

Tags: java, android, generics, kotlin, interface

I am having a hard time with refactoring generic Java code to Kotlin as it is more strict. I do not know what to do in the situation that I have.

First of all I have `interface TopicController` having abstract subscription methods of which some of them contain a parameter `type: Class<T>`. Here, `<T>` should implement the class `Message`. (`<T: Message>`)

I also have an implementation of the TopicController namely `TopicControllerImpl`. This class has a list of nodes: `val nodes: MutableList<TopicNode<T>>`. Also in this case `T` should implement `Message`.

To accomplish this I am trying to append the implement definition to the class like: `TopicControllerImpl<T : Message>`. But, the functions in `TopicController` also needs to have this implement notation and it can not be derrived from `TopicControllerImpl`.

Defining it vice versa, so with `interface TopicController<T : Message>` forces me to define a `Message` for the `TopicController`, so: `class TopicControllerImpl(args) : TopicController<*One type argument expected for interface TopicController<T : Message>*>`.

So to be clear: the following code does **not** compile succesfully:

> TopicControllerImpl

```
class TopicControllerImpl<T: Message>/** ?? */(*[args]*) : TopicController {
   private val nodes: MutableList<TopicNode<T>>

   override fun subscribe(topic: String, type: Class<T>, subscriber: Messenger) {
        val node = findOrCreateNode(topic, type)
        node.addListener(subscriber)
   }

   private fun findOrCreateNode(topic: String, type: Class<T>): TopicNode<T> {
        var node = findNode<T>(topic)
        if (node != null) {
            return node
        }
        // If node doesn't exist yet, create it, run it and add it to the collection
        node = TopicNode(topic, type)
        executor.execute(node, configuration)


        nodes.add(node)

        return node
    } 

    // other functions...
}
```

> TopicController

```
interface TopicController<T : Message>{ /** ?? */

     fun subscribe(topic: String, type: Class<T>, subscriber: Messenger)

     // Other methods
}
```

So I wonder how I can fix it sothat it compiles successfully... Hopefully I am a bit clear, if you have questions please ask for more details.

Comment: Just change your class syntax to this `class TopicControllerImpl<T: Message>/** ?? */(*[args]*) : TopicController<T>`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per **type inference** in kotlin, if your parent is having *Wildcard type* as class representation, you'll need to provide it when you inherit from them in child (it's same thing in java).

In such case, your `TopicController` is of Type `T` having `Message` as reflection.

So, when you inherit *(or extend)* from it meaning at the time of implementation on **child class or interface** you must provide it explicitly.

Look at the example below :

```
interface Parent<T : SomeClass> { // Parent can be an abstract class too
    // Some methods
}
```

then once we implement it on any child,

```
class Child<T: SomeClass> : Parent<T> // We'll need to define T here for parent as it's unknown while inheriting
{
    // Some overridden methods
}
```